# How can you databind a single object in .NET?

Tags: .net, data-binding

I would like to use a component that exposes the datasource property, but instead of supplying the datasource with whole list of objects, I would like to use only simple object. Is there any way to do this ?

The mentioned component is DevExpress.XtraDataLayout.DataLayoutControl - this is fairly irrelevant to the question though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Databinding expects an IEnumerable object, because it enumorates over it just like a foreach loop does.

So to do this, just wrap your single object in an IEnumerable.

Even this would work:

```
DataBindObject.DataSource = new List<YourObject>().Add(YourObjectInstance);
```

Comment: Or `DataBindObject.DataSource = new List<YourObject>(){ YourObjectInstance };` might suit better

Comment: `List<T>.Add` returns `void` not an `IEnumerable`, so the example would result in a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET2.0 you can use the generic collections to make this single object
a list of only one object in it that you can databind to any server control
using the objectdatasource, e.g.

```
List<clsScannedDriverLicense> DriverLicenses = new
List<clsScannedDriverLicense>();
//this creates a generic collection for you that you can return from
//your BLL to the ObjectDataSource
DriverLicenses.Add(TheOneObjectThatYouHaveofType_c lsDriverLicense);
```

Then your ObjectDataSource would look like that:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsDL" runat="server"
SelectMethod="OrdersByCustomer"
TypeName="YourBLL.UtiltiesClassName"
DataObjectTypeName="clsScannedDriverLicense">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

[Source](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t122605-can-you-still-databind-to-a-single-object-in-asp-net-20.html)

Comment: A side note, but people really use ObjectDataSource? I've never seen one use of it outside of MS examples...Its so ugly.

Comment: The ObjectDataSource was a copy&paste from the cited source. I have almost never seen it in the wild tough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have much choice other than using an class that implements IEnumerable<T>. Even if the DataSource property was smart enough to take a scalar object, it would probably convert it internally to a vector.

I would however consider using a simple array rather than a List<T> as this will result in fewer memory allocations. If you don't like the array syntax (and also to increase readability) you could use a helper method:

T[] DataSourceHelper::ToVector(T scalar) {
    return new T[] { scalar };
  }

Answer (score 1):

I'm after the same thing you are.  I've posted a new question [Two-way databinding of a custom templated asp.net control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854234/two-way-databinding-of-a-custom-templated-asp-net-control) that has a bit of a lead.  See what you can make of it...

Answer (score 0):

Using this in my formView:

```
databoundControl.DataSource = new [] { singleObject };
databoundControl.DataBind();
```